# Create a Class, with a GUI....trouble with syntax

Tags: python, class, tkinter

```
class ClassName:
    import tkinter, re, uuid
    from tkinter.constants import *
    import tkinter.messagebox
    import socket, os, subprocess, multiprocessing, sys
    from getmac import get_mac_address as gma
    import getmac, paramiko
    import gpio
    import time, requests, sudo
    from subprocess import Popen
 
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.p.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())   
        self.p.connect("X.0.0.X", port = , username=" ", password=" ")

    def get_ports(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Configure Software", "Configure Access")

        button3 = tkinter.Button(frame,text="Configure", fg="pink", bg="white", command=get_ports)
        button3.pack(side=LEFT)
        
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Client/Server Information", "Lets Be Nosey")
    
        button4 = tkinter.Button(frame,text=" Client/Server Information", command=get_ports)
        button4.pack(side=LEFT)
    
        exec(open('path').read(), globals())

    def pinger(self, job_q, results_q):
        """
        Do Ping
        :param job_q:
        :param results_q:
        :return:
        """
        DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        while True:

            ip = job_q.get()

            if ip is None:
                break

            try:
                subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c1', ip],
                                    stdout=DEVNULL)
                results_q.put(ip)
            except:
                pass

    def get_my_ip(self):
        """
        Find my IP address
        :return:
        """
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        ip = s.getsockname()[0]
        s.close()
        return ip

    def map_network(self, pool_size=255):
        """
        Maps the network
        :param pool_size: amount of parallel ping processes
        :return: list of valid ip addresses
        """

        ip_list = list()

        ip_parts = get_my_ip().split('.')
        base_ip = ip_parts[0] + '.' + ip_parts[1] + '.' + ip_parts[2] + '.'

        jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
        results = multiprocessing.Queue()

        pool = [multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs, results)) for i in range(pool_size)]

        for p in pool:
            p.start()

        for i in range(1, 255):
            jobs.put(base_ip + '{0}'.format(i))

        for p in pool:
            jobs.put(None)

        for p in pool:
            p.join()

        while not results.empty():
            ip = results.get()
            ip_list.append(ip)

        return ip_list

    def test_log(self):
        print('test log')
        print('Mapping...')
        lst = map_network()
        print(lst)
        addresses = subprocess.check_output(['arp', '-a'])
        print(addresses)

    def ssh_connect(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
        ssh.connect("X.0.0.X", port, "user", "password")
        chan=ssh.get_transport().open_session()
        chan.get_pty()
        f = chan.makefile()
        chan.exec_command("sudo dmesg")
        chan.send("password\n")
        print(f.read())
        ssh.close()
        pass

    def raspi_connecter(self):
        print("Below is the output from the shell script in terminal")
        # subprocess.call('ssh user@X.0.0.X', shell=True)
        proc = subprocess.Popen('ssh user@X.0.0.X', shell=True)
        try:
            outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=8)
                # print(f.returncode)
        except TimeoutError:
            proc.kill()

            cmd = ['sh commands3.sh']
            f = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            for line in f.stdout:
                print(line)
                f.wait()

    def keypad_tests(self):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.p.exec_command('sudo nano /etc/hostname')
        opt2 = stdout.readlines()
        opt2 = "".join(opt2)
        # sudo journalctl -u spiderentry.service | sudo tee ../../full_log.sh 
        print(opt2)
        input("press enter to continue")

    # sudo touch and sudo tee (wipe the file (X_log) and recreate/write upon command execution)

            


    if __name__=='__main__':
        tk = tkinter.Tk()
        

        frame = tkinter.Frame(tk, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=2)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=100)

        label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="GUI IP/Port Scanner")
        label.pack(fill=X, expand=100)
        
        button1 = tkinter.Button(frame,text="Exit",fg="red", bg="black", command=tk.destroy)
        button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        
        button2 = tkinter.Button(frame,text="Start", fg="blue", bg="green", command=map_network)
        button2.pack(side=LEFT)
        button5 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Port Scanner", command=test_log)
        button5.pack(side=LEFT)
        button6 = tkinter.Button(frame, text="connect keypad", command=raspi_connecter)
        button6.pack(side=LEFT)
        button7 = tkinter.Button(frame, text= "run tests", command= keypad_tests)
        button7.pack(side=LEFT)

        tk.mainloop()

    # release the function (threading, multiprocessing)
    # # open file and pull lines out commands.sh
```

May be just a mental block, but for some reason when i made this a class in order to properly run the last function, i have a syntax error and it is now telling me that i have undefined variables from all of my imports, and as you can see i have used the imports and functions properly but when it is made into a class the error shows. if this is a simple fix, awesome, as i said may be just a brain fart.

Error note: " File "/Users/andysiar/Desktop/Python_Projects/HW_Test_Auto_GUI/gui_main.py", line 1
class Spiderdoor:
^
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level"

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Chances are, you will find the error yourself doing so. As it stands, your question isn't sufficiently prepared and considered off-topic. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Include the entire error code please

Comment: Error note is added @CoolCloud...along with that error note my "problems" tab in VS code is littered with undefined variables (paramiko, subprocess, etc) showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you've put all your `import` statements inside your class. That makes the variables that get created class variables, which you probably don't want. You're not accessing them as class variables later, so it doesn't look like you intend to be doing this. Furthermore, using a wildcard import like `from tkinter.constants import *` is not allowed anywhere but at the top level.

The obvious fix is to move the imports outside the class:

```
import tkinter, re, uuid
from tkinter.constants import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import socket, os, subprocess, multiprocessing, sys
from getmac import get_mac_address as gma
import getmac, paramiko
import gpio
import time, requests, sudo
from subprocess import Popen

class ClassName:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this was the simple fix but what i also didn't realize until further thinking was the formatting/syntax that needed to be done in the functions and buttons. thank you for your assistance here